# How to set up Conditional Formatting in Excel to highlight a row based off unrelated table

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a table in Excel with an ID column that has various values. I want the entire row highlighted if the ID cell of that row contains a value located in a different table in that same Excel sheet.

I've tried making new rules but it never searches against a different table. Setting it at the individual value only highlights the cell.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/lzbloZn.png]

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please edit your post and add some screenshots and description of the problem so we can better understand and help you. Are they formatted tables or ranges? What have you tried so far? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From your example, I assume that if any ID in column A also appears in column F, you would like columns A thru D to be highlighted.  You should be able to do this as follows:

1. Select all the data you want the conditional formatting to apply to.
2. Start a new conditional formatting rule, and choose 'Use a formula to determine which cells to format'.
3. Set the style you want for the highlight formatting.
4. Enter the formula `=NOT(ISNA(MATCH($A2,$F$2:$F$7)))` then click OK.

The `MATCH()` part tries to find the value from A2 in the range F2 thru F7, and returns a number, or `#N/A` if it fails. The `NOT(ISNA())` part means the formula is true for every row where the match didn't fail.  Because we used `$A2` rather than `$A$2`, this checks the correct cell in each row, not just A2 every time.

Note that the formula above uses the fixed range F2:F7, and will need to be edited if you need a different length list.  You could make it more flexible by using `$F:$F` instead (which would check against anything in the whole of column F), or by using a named range, e.g. `=NOT(ISNA(MATCH($A2, my_range)))`.  You can set a name for a range using Formulas/Define name, which might make it easier to manage your data.  Setting meaningful names for ranges can help you remember what formulas are doing when you come back to them in the future.